# open command in perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am try to use open command in perl. But getting and error as follows.

**Command**

`open(IN_TRIALS, '<', "F:/2010_nist_sre_test_set/data/eval/keys/coreext-coreext.trialkey.csv") or die "cannot open trials list";`

**Error**
cannot open trials.

how to fix this?

Comment: Did you test the command with placing the file - temporary - in the same directory and referencing it directly with ..., "coreext-coreext.trialkey.csv" ? You may also want to take a look at the hints given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265765/7773582.

Comment: Be sure to include the error message itself in your `die` -- something like `"cannot open trials list: $!"`.

Comment: Did you mean to include the `linux` tag? `F:/...` is a Windows-style file path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure the file exists in the location: `F:/2010_nist_sre_test_set/data/eval/keys/coreext-coreext.trialkey.csv`.

Use a modern way to read a file, using a lexical filehandle:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "F:/2010_nist_sre_test_set/data/eval/keys/coreext-coreext.trialkey.csv";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
...
...
close $fh;
```

If you're reading a `csv` file then it is recommended to use Perl Module [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS).

If you use `Text::CSV_XS`, here is the syntax:

```
use Text::CSV_XS;
 
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });

my $filename = "F:/2010_nist_sre_test_set/data/eval/keys/coreext-coreext.trialkey.csv";
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "$filename: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    #do the necessary operation
}
close $fh;
```